# Excerpt functions is removing the forward slash on the url

Tags: excerpt

Excerpt functions is removing the forward slash on the url - I am completely lost here I can't find a way to make it work.

I am very new on php programming any help would be very appreciated.

I am calling this function on my index.php

```
index.php :

<?php echo get_excerpt_max_charlength('260', true) ?>   



functions.php :


function get_excerpt_max_charlength($charlength, $readmore = true) {
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
$charlength++;

if ( mb_strlen( $excerpt ) > $charlength ) {
    $subex = mb_substr( $excerpt, 0, $charlength - 5 );
    $exwords = explode( ' ', $subex );
    $excut = - ( mb_strlen( $exwords[ count( $exwords ) - 1 ] ) );
    if ( $excut < 0 ) {
        $str = mb_substr( $subex, 0, $excut );
    } else {
        $str = $subex;
    }
    return $readmore ? $str . '&hellip; <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . __('read more') . '</a>' : $str . '&hellip;';
} else {
    return $excerpt;
}
}
```

Forward slash removed :

[image]

UPDATE I have found the fix - not bad for someone is new in programming.

```
 return $readmore ? $str . '<a class="more-link" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">'. __('read more') .'</a>' . '</a>' : $str . '&hellip;';
```

Comment: While you are new to programming, I would advice you to refrain from bad coding practices. First of all, never ever use those crappy php shortags (*`<?=`*) you are using. It is not recommended for use, use proper php tags (*`<?php` and `?>`*). Also, properly indend your code to make is easier to read. Sloppy code hides bugs

Comment: @PieterGoosen well I have to disagree regarding the short_open_tag - they are fine IF defined on php.ini. Regarding the indend Subline does the work for me, sorry for copying and past it.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I wonder why you have voted negative in my question

Comment: @PieterGoosen `<?=` is absolutely fine for templates. These are **not** the regular short open tags.

Comment: @NunoS please post your update as an answer. Please note, if you have issues with how people vote, please raise an issue on [meta], the main stack is not meant to discuss off topic issues

Comment: @toscho Thanks for the info, still, it is crappy syntax that does not make sense

Comment: @PieterGoosen if it doesn't make sense you can help me out in making the code less "crappy" or instead you can just let it go and stop it to give useless comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix:

```
 return $readmore ? $str . '<a class="more-link" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">'. __('read more') .'</a>' . '</a>' : $str . '&hellip;';
```